# get redirect link with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I have a link: `https://uchebnik.mos.ru/exam/test/test_by_binding/2511452/homework/152004494/variant/45906101/num/1?generation_context_type=lesson&external_binding_id=2230159&referer=homework&registration={my_token}`
If I have logged in to the site, then I should be automatically redirected by the link: `https://uchebnik.mos.ru/exam/test/training_spec/124085/task/1?registration={my_token}`
I use cookies for authorization: "auth_token", "profile_id", "udacl".
How i can get this redirect link?
I use urllib.open, request.url, but the link does not change.
My guess is that this is due to JavaScript authorization, but I tried the requests_html library with JS support, but the result does not change.
Preferably without using webdrivers.

Comment: Look with browser developer tools how this redirect was done. It possible in [Persistent Logs](https://superuser.com/questions/242138/how-to-track-url-redirects-in-the-browser) mode. It can be server answer for some request, JS redirect or html `http-equiv="refresh"`. In some cases this sequance can be reproduced without webdriver. Also use `requests` with `session` to handling cookies correctly.

Comment: I looked at this data. Saw the most possible `refer`. Type was `plain`. Initiator was `698.6fa75c1169a4fafbec37.chunk.js`. How i can get this url?

Comment: If initiator is `.js` it seems to be redirect through `window.location` object, and you should use webdriver on way or another. In between, `requests_html` already do it for you: [the first time you ever run the render() method, it will download Chromium into your home directory](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#javascript-support)